# Set one field in state after POST (set price in table after bid)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've component with products table I want to dynamic set price after bid using this.state.

State

```
export default class MyProductsList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [],
    users: [],
    response: "",
    myProducts: "",
    newPrice: "",
    productId: "",
    typeResponse: "",
  };
```

Fragment of bid function

```
  bidProduct(item) {
    const token = tokenFixed;
    const user = loginFixed;

    const bid = {
      productId: item.productId,
      newProductPrice: this.state.newPrice,
      login: user,
      sessionKey: token,
    };
    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:8080/product/setNewPrice`, bid)
      .then((res) => {
        this.state.products.map((item) => {
          if (item.productId === bid.productId) {
            this.setState({ products: (item.price = bid.newProductPrice) });
          }
        });

        this.setState({ response: "Bid has been submitted successfully!" });
      })
```

Fragment of table

```
            {this.state.products.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={item.productId}>
                      <td># {item.productId}</td>
                      <td>Status TODO</td>
                      <td>{item.title}</td>
                      <td>{item.price}</td>
                      <td>{item.description}</td>
```

I want to setState of {item.price} after bidProduct is successful

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved that case.

If you have the same

1. First after POST if success - you need to copy your current array

```
        const nextProducts = [...this.state.products];
```

2. Then search for item which you want update and set price of this item

```
        nextProducts.map((i) => {
          if (i.productId === bid.productId) i.price = bid.newProductPrice;
        });
```

3. Finally setState of your current products with the new one

```
        this.setState({ products: nextProducts });
```

4. Final code looks like

```
  bidProduct(item) {
    const token = tokenFixed;
    const user = loginFixed;

    const bid = {
      productId: item.productId,
      newProductPrice: this.state.newPrice,
      login: user,
      sessionKey: token,
    };

    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:8080/product/setNewPrice`, bid)
      .then((res) => {
        const nextProducts = [...this.state.products];
        nextProducts.map((i) => {
          if (i.productId === bid.productId) i.price = bid.newProductPrice;
        });
        this.setState({ products: nextProducts });
        this.setState({ response: "Bid has been submitted successfully!" });
      })
```